# jar file for hultig.sumo.Sentence package and org.artarus.snowball.ext.englishStemmer

Tags: java, jar, lucene, libraries

I have a java source code which uses **hultig.sumo.Sentence package** and **org.artarus.snowball.ext.englishStemmer**.And i need the jar file containing this  this packages to add it to the libraries in NetBeans.   can any one please help me? I did not get the problem resolved by using **lucene-snowball-3.0.1** for org.artarus.snowball.ext.englishStemmer.And i did not get any jar file for **hultig.sumo.Sentence**... Thanks in advance..

Comment: i have checked the url but it is asking me to provide  a username and password for that which i dont have and no provision of sign up even

Comment: You can register [here](http://www.di.ubi.pt/~jpaulo/hultiglib/registo.html). This is free and only has one purpose as described: `This is just for keeping track about the number of users interested in our resources.`

Comment: Thank you so much @LostKatana it worked for hultig.sumo.Sentence.But still having problem with org.artarus.snowball.ext.englishStemmer

Comment: `org.artarus.snowball.ext.englishStemmer` is from [here](http://snowball.tartarus.org/download.php). On Windows you can extract the jar by using 7zip.

Comment: I have downloaded the libstemmer_java from the site you have provided but I dont know how to add it in the NetBeans in libraries.It isn't a jar file.Please tell me how to add it in the libraries in NetBeans.

Comment: you need to extract the file..it's compressed..you can use 7zip for example

Answer (score 0):

The jar file can be downloaded [here](http://www.di.ubi.pt/~jpaulo/hultiglib/).
And the API is located [here](http://www.di.ubi.pt/~jpaulo/hultiglib/javadoc/)

org.artarus.snowball.ext.englishStemmer you can download [here](http://snowball.tartarus.org/download.php)